Instalación de KIVY
Hola estava intentado instalar kivy para un futuro proyecto, es la primera vez que trabajo con python de esta forma, a la hora de instalarlo me sale un error, he probado de instalar todos las librerias previas pero no hay manera de que funcione, adjunto parte del error que me sale y lo que he echo hasta el momento:
Error:
Cosas que ya e echo para solucionar y no han funcionado:


Hola, la ultima version estable de Kivy (2.3.0) no soporta Python 3.13 (version de Python relativamente nueva), usa Python 3.12.
